# Overflow auto on p tags as a site wide default?

Tags: css, overflow, paragraph

I have a large number of instances on my site where ive got an image floated to the side of text. When the text is long enough to wrap below the image I dont want it to take up the full width of the div, instead I want all the text to stay vertically aligned.

I can do this by setting overflow auto to the p tag. Ive had to do this so many times im considering making this rule global for all p tags. What the risks / down sides to doing this? Ive done it as a test and had a quick look and everything looks fine.

```
<div>
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg" />

  <p>Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text Here is my text</p>
</div>

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
p {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kdbJp

Comment: This is interesting. Typically I'd use a column layout to achieve this, but the auto works. I'm wondering what will happen with multiple images. One thing to consider is that it only will shift the `p` element that is directly interacting with the image. Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/elizh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, as always, a judgement call. In my experience, styling tags directly will lead to unintentional side effects and make long term maintenance harder. (What if you actually need a 'p' tag to be a paragraph later?

My recommendation would be to use a class on the div and preface all the relevant selectors with it. Also look in to the new html5 tags 'figure' and 'figcaption'.

```
.media-box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.media-box img {
   /* ... */
}

.media-box p {
   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the spec says that `overflow:auto` is user agent-dependent, the risk of doing this is that it not achieve the desired behaviour in all browsers. Also, you may see scroll bars on some browsers because the spec recommends that behaviour for overflowing elements.

> **auto**
>
> The behavior of the 'auto' value is user agent-dependent, but should cause a scrolling mechanism to be provided for overflowing boxes.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow

The way this works is by creating a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

Also, found a [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) article about it. Seems to mention that setting a width or height is important for correct functionality in some browsers.

Comment: I just took a look in FF, IE, and Chrome, and they all appear to be rendering the same. Older browsers may have issues though. +1 for the agent-dependent info.

Comment: The spec recommends scrollbars for "overflowing boxes".  Assuming no set width or height (or other means of constricting dimensions), the `p` elements will never overflow.  Just clarifying because your wording seems to imply recommendation of scroll bars all the time.  (I may be reading too far into your wording)

Answer (score 0):

The risks/downsides would be in the case that you **don't** want the above behaviour, you will then have to replace the `overflow: auto` on those `<p>` tags that you want a different behaviour on.

The questions I would ask myself are:

- Who is going to be maintaining/developing this site in the future?
- Are they likely to want their `<p>` tags to behave this same way?
- Is it easy for them to override the behaviour?

In most cases I would favour a simple CSS class that I can apply to the `<p>` tags myself. Any future developer will be able to see the classes applied to the p tags and copy the behaviour. Anyone who wants a normal `<p>` just doesn't apply that class.

I would only favour blanket element selectors like this for theme type styling (i.e. "I want ALL `<p>` tags to look a certain way on this website". If you don't want that, I would faviour creating a class specifically for the prupose with a nice descriptive name.

The choice, however, is ultimately yours.

Answer (score 0):

overflow:auto on paragraphs is bad practice. A paragraphs nature is to wrap around.  There are a number of techniques you could use here.  But I would just set the paragraph and image to their own widths so that they each only take up a certain amount of space.

```
article
  img
  p

article img{float: left, width: 20%}
article p{float: left, width: 80%}
```

This would be your best practice, and that is because this allows your elements to only take up the specified width that you have requested, and no more, no less.  Without overwriting other elements space.  In honest, there is no real need for overflow:anything

http://jsfiddle.net/5njNa/